# Get $_GET parameters in unit testing Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit

I am new in testing. I want to test my service and function, but this gets  $_GET parameter. How I can simulate get parameter in test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Symfony2, you should abstract your code away from direct usage of PHP superglobals. Instead pass a Request object to your service:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyService
{
    public function doSomething(Request $request)
    {
        $foo = $request->query->get('foo');
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your unit tests, do something like:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyServiceTest
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $service = new MyService();
        $request = new Request(array('foo' => 'bar'));
        $service->doSomething($request);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You could also consider making your service even more generic, and just pass the values you want when calling it's methods:

```
class MyService
{
    public function doSomething($foo)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

$service = new MyService();
$service->doSomething($request->query->get('foo');
```